# Tools to translate x86-64 ELF to PPC (or i386 decompilation)

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, disassemblers, decompiler

I've been working on a project on an IBM POWER8 system. I'd like to translate some very simple binaries from x86-64 to PPC.

Is there a tool that can either:

1. Translate the binary from x86-64 to PPC (similar to how Apple Rosetta did PPC to x86-64)
2. Decompile the x86-64 binary into C code (doesn't need to be human readable) so that I can recompile it on a PPC system

I'd love to know if there's any other way to get that done as well.

EDIT: Also, I'm not comfortable using commercial software, but am okay with closed-source.

Thanks!

Comment: To the person who downvoted, I'd love to know why and learn from that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1, there is [QEMU](https://www.qemu.org/) which can be built for PPC and supports i386 and x86-64 emulation. If you run Linux, there may already be a precompiled package available for your distro.

For 2, there *are* some decompilers which can produce C pseudocode from x86-64 binaries. Alternatively, tools like [McSema](https://github.com/trailofbits/mcsema) can perform *lifting* to LLVM bitcode which can then be recompiled to PPC (in theory).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! With QEMU, I can see that User-Mode Emulation would allow me to run that binary on PPC. However, is there software that actually "translates" the binary itself to run natively on PPC? Also, sorry I didn't state this in the answer, but McSema uses commercial software, which I can't use. Are there any alternatives to this? Thanks again!

Comment: if you want to have completely independent native PPC binaries you'll have to go with option 2. Note that Rosetta worked like QEMU - it ran unmodified binaries via emulation.

Comment: Alright, thanks! Do you know any resources that would help me get that emulation setup? Again, I don’t want to install an operating system emulating PowerPC, but I want to run an emulated PowerPC program. I can’t find too many resources online for that.

Comment: wait, first you ask  about emulating x86 on PPC and now the other way around? Ask on superuser.com or something, this does not seem related to RE.

Comment: Sorry was confused, was leaving for a flight; meant I don’t want an OS emulating x86, but instead emulating an x86 program on PPC

Comment: `qemu-user` should allow you to do that. In any case, it's not really an RE issue. If you need help getting it work, try SuperUser.